# Get mouse position within div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouse position relative to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824332/mouse-position-relative-to-div)
>   [getting mouse position with javascript within canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848310/getting-mouse-position-with-javascript-within-canvas)

How can I get the position of the mouse within a canvas that is a fixed size but has an automatic margin?

I can't make its position fixed and can't just use the regular mouse position on the page.

This code works perfectly:

```
mouseX = e.pageX - div.offsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - div.offsetTop;
```

Comment: Google is your friend - http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: Please post some sample code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or another like it if you are having a specific issue to examine.

Comment: Has this been answered [elsewhere](/questions/4848310/getting-mouse-position-with-javascript-within-canvas?rq=1)?

Comment: Please do not remove the duplicate links; reviewers still want to see what your question was closed *for*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var divPos = {};
var offset = $("#divid").offset();
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    divPos = {
        left: e.pageX - offset.left,
        top: e.pageY - offset.top
    };
});
```

Comment: What about not using jQuery

Comment: @bryan - I'm sure it can be done without jQuery, but it would be pretty complicated

Comment: MDN says `pageX` is not standard and should not be used. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX I had some trouble using it with foreignObject for example.

Comment: @charles - the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of a jQuery event object are standardized.

Comment: oh yeah it's a jQuery event, sorry.

Comment: using `getBoundingClientRect` instead and `addEventListener` you won’t need jquery:::
`var offset = document.querySelector('#divid').getBoundingClientRect();
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var pos = {
    left: e.pageX - offset.left,
    top: e.pageY - offset.top
  }
}`

...not tried but should work

Answer (score 4):

Use `event.layerX` and `event.layerY` to get mouse position relative to the current element:

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  var mousePos = {'x': e.layerX, 'y': e.layerY};
});
```

Comment: That's a cool feature, too bad it's deprecated.

Comment: @blex It's not deprecated, it's non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX

Comment: It should also be mentioned that this can cause some serious issues as the definition of Layer can easily be changed by a simple flick of the wrist, thereby changing the layerX and layerY.

Comment: From MDN: "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user."

Answer (score -3):

Taken from jQuery site: [Jquery Tutorial site](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   });
```

NOTE: fixed syntax

Comment: Why was this marked down?

Comment: Because `pageX` and `pageY` are not relative to the container.