# Add pin to image on click and get x & y coordinates of pin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, marker

I have an image of a map of southern Wales. What I would like to do is click on the map and it will drop an pin/marker on the image. The marker needs to move if I click elsewhere on the map though.

I also need to capture the x & y coordinates of the pin so that I can store this and then use it later on on the site.

I have had a look through past Q&As but none of them where similar to what I need.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could have a read of this and see whether the suggestions can be adapted for your scenario and with an "onClick" handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651306/get-mouse-position-within-div

Comment: Hi Chris

Those are good examples but won't work for me. Need to drop a pin/marker where I have click on the image as and save the coordinates

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LQqGS/ - You will need to update it with an AJAX to store the coordinates